Rewrite rule to resolve 2 use cases
I have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:
RewriteRule ^projects/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ /projects/$1/seo.$2.php  

For example, the following rule works fine and I would like to keep it as is:
URL: domain.com/projects/book/read-more opens /projects/book/seo.read-more.php page

What I need is, in addition, to modify it or add another rule to display only the directory and resolve in the index.php file if the address ends with the directory.
URL: domain.com/projects/book to open /projects/book/index.php page

I've tried putting the following rule above the current one but it didn't work.
RewriteRule ^projects/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ /projects/$1/index.php [NC,L]

What am I missing?

Could you try these:
# Match the directory and point to index.php
RewriteRule ^projects/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /projects/$1/index.php [NC,L]

# Match to handle additional segments
RewriteRule ^projects/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /projects/$1/seo.$2.php [NC,L]

I tested them on htaccess.madewithlove.com and got the results you were expecting

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:
# make index.php default handler of a directory
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash to directories first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# forward to corresponding seo file only if it is present
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/seo.$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(projects/[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/seo.$2.php [NC,L]


Well-documented/commented code!
